# ajax search function didn't wok on opencart

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```js
This is my checkout page HTML code with js code.


<?php echo $header; ?>
<div class="container">
  <ul class="breadcrumb">
    <?php foreach ($breadcrumbs as $breadcrumb) { ?>
    <li><a href="<?php echo $breadcrumb['href']; ?>"><?php echo $breadcrumb['text']; ?></a></li>
    <?php } ?>
  </ul>
  <?php if ($error_warning) { ?>
  <div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> <?php echo $error_warning; ?>
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button>
  </div>
  <?php } ?>
  <div class="row"><?php echo $column_left; ?>
    <?php if ($column_left && $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-6'; ?>
    <?php } elseif ($column_left || $column_right) { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-9'; ?>
    <?php } else { ?>
    <?php $class = 'col-sm-12'; ?>
    <?php } ?>
    <div id="content" class="<?php echo $class; ?>"><?php echo $content_top; ?>
      <h1><?php echo $heading_title; ?></h1>
      <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_option; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-checkout-option">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php if (!$logged && $account != 'guest') { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } else { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-address">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-shipping-method">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <?php } ?>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-payment-method">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            <h4 class="panel-title"><?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?></h4>
          </div>
          <div class="panel-collapse collapse" id="collapse-checkout-confirm">
            <div class="panel-body"></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <?php echo $content_bottom; ?></div>
    <?php echo $column_right; ?></div>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript"><!--
$(document).on('change', 'input[name=\'account\']', function() {
 if ($('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title > *').is('a')) { 
  if (this.value == 'register') {
   $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
  } else {
   $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
  }
 } else {
  if (this.value == 'register') {
   $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?>');
  } else {
   $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?>');
  } 
 }
});

<?php if (!$logged) { ?> 
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/login',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
           $('#collapse-checkout-option .panel-body').html(html);
          
   $('#collapse-checkout-option').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-checkout-option" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_option; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
   
   $('a[href=\'#collapse-checkout-option\']').trigger('click');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});     
<?php } else { ?>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address',
        dataType: 'html',
        success: function(html) {
            $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').html(html);
            
   $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');

   $('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-address\']').trigger('click');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});
<?php } ?>

// Checkout
$(document).delegate('#button-account', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/' + $('input[name=\'account\']:checked').val(),
        dataType: 'html',
        beforeSend: function() {
         $('#button-account').button('loading');
  },      
        complete: function() {
   $('#button-account').button('reset');
        },          
        success: function(html) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            
            $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').html(html);

   if ($('input[name=\'account\']:checked').val() == 'register') {
    $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_account; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
   } else {
    $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
   } 
   
   $('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-address\']').trigger('click');
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    });
});

// Login
$(document).delegate('#button-login', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/login/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-checkout-option :input'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
         $('#button-login').button('loading');
  },  
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-login').button('reset');
        },              
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
   
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                $('#collapse-checkout-option .panel-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['warning'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
           
    // Highlight any found errors
    $('input[name=\'email\']').parent().addClass('has-error'); 
    $('input[name=\'password\']').parent().addClass('has-error');    
     }
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
});

// Register
$(document).delegate('#button-register', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/register/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'date\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'datetime-local\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'time\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'password\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address textarea, #collapse-payment-address select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
   $('#button-register').button('loading');
  },  
        complete: function() {
            $('#button-register').button('reset');
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            $('.form-group').removeClass('has-error');
               
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];                
            } else if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-danger"><i class="fa fa-exclamation-circle"></i> ' + json['error']['warning'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }
                
    for (i in json['error']) {
     var element = $('#input-payment-' + i.replace('_', '-'));
     
     if ($(element).parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
      $(element).parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
     } else {
      $(element).after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
     }
    }
    
    // Highlight any found errors
    $('.text-danger').parent().addClass('has-error');     
            } else {
                <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>              
                var shipping_address = $('#payment-address input[name=\'shipping_address\']:checked').prop('value');
                
                if (shipping_address) {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_method',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(html) {
       // Add the shipping address
                            $.ajax({
                                url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                                dataType: 'html',
                                success: function(html) {
                                    $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').html(html);
         
         $('#collapse-shipping-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
                                },
                                error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                                    alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                                }
                            }); 
       
       $('#collapse-shipping-method .panel-body').html(html);
                            
       $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
   
          $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-method\']').trigger('click');

       $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
       $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');       
       $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>'); 
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    }); 
                } else {
                    $.ajax({
                        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        success: function(html) {
                            $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').html(html);
                            
       $('#collapse-shipping-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
   
       $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-address\']').trigger('click');
       
       $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
       $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');       
       $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>'); 
                        },
                        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                        }
                    });         
                }
                <?php } else { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-payment-method .panel-body').html(html);
                        
      $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
      
      $('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-method\']').trigger('click');
      
      $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');     
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });                 
                <?php } ?>

                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').html(html);
                        
      $('#collapse-payment-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
            }    
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
    }); 
});

// Payment Address  
$(document).delegate('#button-payment-address', 'click', function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address/save',
        type: 'post',
        data: $('#collapse-payment-address input[type=\'text\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'date\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'datetime-local\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'time\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'password\'], #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'checkbox\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'radio\']:checked, #collapse-payment-address input[type=\'hidden\'], #collapse-payment-address textarea, #collapse-payment-address select'),
        dataType: 'json',
        beforeSend: function() {
         $('#button-payment-address').button('loading');
  },  
        complete: function() {
   $('#button-payment-address').button('reset');
        },          
        success: function(json) {
            $('.alert, .text-danger').remove();
            
            if (json['redirect']) {
                location = json['redirect'];
            } else if (json['error']) {
                if (json['error']['warning']) {
                    $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').prepend('<div class="alert alert-warning">' + json['error']['warning'] + '<button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">&times;</button></div>');
                }
                    
    for (i in json['error']) {
     var element = $('#input-payment-' + i.replace('_', '-'));
     
     if ($(element).parent().hasClass('input-group')) {
      $(element).parent().after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
     } else {
      $(element).after('<div class="text-danger">' + json['error'][i] + '</div>');
     }
    }
        
    // Highlight any found errors
    $('.text-danger').parent().parent().addClass('has-error');    
            } else {
                <?php if ($shipping_required) { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/shipping_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-shipping-address .panel-body').html(html);
                        
      $('#collapse-shipping-address').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-shipping-address" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_address; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
      
      $('a[href=\'#collapse-shipping-address\']').trigger('click');

      $('#collapse-shipping-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_shipping_method; ?>');
      $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?>');
      $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });
                <?php } else { ?>
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_method',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-payment-method .panel-body').html(html);
                     
      $('#collapse-payment-method').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<a href="#collapse-payment-method" data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" class="accordion-toggle"><?php echo $text_checkout_payment_method; ?> <i class="fa fa-caret-down"></i></a>');
      
      $('a[href=\'#collapse-payment-method\']').trigger('click');

      $('#collapse-checkout-confirm').parent().find('.panel-heading .panel-title').html('<?php echo $text_checkout_confirm; ?>');
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                }); 
                <?php } ?>
                
                $.ajax({
                    url: 'index.php?route=checkout/payment_address',
                    dataType: 'html',
                    success: function(html) {
                        $('#collapse-payment-address .panel-body').html(html);
                    },
                    error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
                        alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
                    }
                });             
            }     
        },
        error: function(xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert(thrownError + "\r\n" + xhr.statusText + "\r\n" + xhr.responseText);
        }
   }); 
});
</script>
<?php echo $footer;?>
```

I'm working with opencart 2.0.1.0 and I've integrated ajax search suggestion plugin on it. Its working perfectly when I logged out of opencart. But while I'm logging in it doesn't work and getting errors,

http://192.168.1.2/opencart/upload/index.php?route=module/search_suggestion/ajax&keyword=s 500 (Internal Server Error).

In checkout page I have particular error while clicking 'continue' button,

"Uncaught Error: cannot call methods on button prior to initialization; attempted to call method 'loading' "

Can anyone help me?

Comment: `500` means the server script is getting an error. Check your PHP error log.

Comment: If you don't post code, there's no way any of us can tell you how to fix the problem.